# Realtime Database for China

Tags: android, database, mobile, real-time

As we know, most of Google Cloud, APIs, websites and services are not accessible in China? So if I am making an app which is using Firebase as its mobile backend, then what equivalent should I consider for China?

Comment: I an not sure that I understand your problem. China is using DNS blocking to block certain domains. It does not matter which database is behind those domains, they can still be blocked.  If I have misunderstood, can you please clarify and I will try my best to help

Comment: @Mawg - Since my app is using Firebase, it will not be accessible for users who use the app in China. So my question is what is the Chinese alternative to Firebase.

Comment: I don't know if Chinese people had created similar realtime database services like those Google offered. Maybe their government don't like this technology?

Comment: I think you miss the point - it does not matter what database you use - the government will block the URL that people use to access your app; they don't need to block any database.  You go to facebook.com, not facebookdatabase.com, so that's what the government will block. Look into using VPNs for people in China to access your service

Comment: You might also want to ask at https://security.stackexchange.com/